# Adding Google Analytics Code

Tags: plugins

I'm 5 minutes new to Craft and G&T, but my client needs GA installed on their new site.

Any thoughts about how to do this?

Also, general SEO questions: are there SEO plugins a la wordpress that you guys can point me to?

Comment: Hi Zac! Don't forget to check out the long list of Craft plugins here: http://straightupcraft.com/craft-plugins. Enjoy your Craft work and your gin and tonics.

Answer (score 5):

Installing GA is easy... you can either [put that info into a Global field](https://craftcms.com/docs/globals), or [include it as a separate Twig template](http://twig.sensiolabs.org/doc/tags/include.html).

As for general SEO... Check out the [SEOmatic plugin](https://github.com/nystudio107/seomatic) or the [Sprout SEO plugin](https://sprout.barrelstrengthdesign.com/craft-plugins/seo).

Answer (score 2):

For general SEO plugins I'd give [SEOMatic](https://github.com/nystudio107/seomatic) a try. I've used it on a number of projects. It's a well supported plugin, regularly updated by the developer.

Answer (score 1):

You can simply just add the google analytics script that it gives you in the _layout.html base file or the google tag manager scripts if you want to add other tracking code as well as google analytics.