# How do you handle SEO on your site?

Tags: templating, seo

How do you guys handle SEO? Do you just make your own meta fields and add them in the template manually or am I missing something? I did notice there are some plugins being developed but there are sites in the wild now so it's been handled some how. Thanks!

Answer (score 17, accepted):

You basically have two options...

**In the world of plugins**, check out the [SEOmatic plugin](https://github.com/nystudio107/seomatic) or [Sprout SEO plugin](http://sprout.barrelstrengthdesign.com/craft-plugins/seo).

On Craft 2, SEOmatic is free, Sprout SEO is $99.

On Craft CMS 3, the [SEOmatic plugin](https://github.com/nystudio107/craft-seomatic) and [Sprout SEO plugin](https://github.com/barrelstrength/craft-sprout-seo) are both available and $99.

**If you'd rather not use a plugin**, then you're on your own to create and implement whatever fields you think you'll need. Depending on how you're approaching SEO, it could be fields like "Keywords", "Description", etc... and/or fields for the Facebook OG tags, or whatever you want! At that point, implementing your SEO fields would be nearly identical to implementing any other fields in Craft.

Comment: Ok great, thanks. Surprised this hasn't been asked before.

Comment: [A variation of it has...](http://craftcms.stackexchange.com/q/2753/45) from which I partially recycled this answer.

Comment: How do you deal with channel "index" or "listing" page metas? Since we can't control de fields of those pages?

Comment: @JCharette I'd recommend posting a new question. Feel free to link back to this one for reference if it helps.

Answer (score 34):

Without having to use a separate Plugin this is a good basic practice on setting up basic SEO for your site.

First create three new fields called "**seoTitle**", "**seoDescription**" and "**seoKeywords**". Put these three fields in a Global group called "**globalSeo**".

In your layout template "*layouts/_layout.html*"

```
    {% set seoTitle = globalSeo.seoTitle %}
    {% set seoDescription = globalSeo.seoDescription %}
    {% set seoKeywords = globalSeo.seoKeywords %}
    <!DOCTYPE html>
    <html>
        <head>
            <title>{% if title is defined %}{{ title }}{% else %}{{ seoTitle }}{% endif %}</title>
            <meta name="description" content="{% if description is defined %}{{ description }}{% else %}{{ seoDescription }}{% endif %}"/>
            <meta name="keywords" content="{{ seoKeywords }}"/>

            {# You can then use the same fields for Facebook tags etc.. or create separate fields. #}
            <meta property="og:title" content="{% if title is defined %}{{ title }}{% else %}{{ seoTitle }}{% endif %}"/>
            <meta property="og:description" content="{% if description is defined %}{{ description }}{% else %}{{ seoDescription }}{% endif %}"/>
        </head>
    <body>
```

You can now per template override these standard variables with your own for that particular page and/or template.

For a template:

```
    {% extends "layouts/_layout" %}
    {% set title = "This is a my custom Page Title" %}
    {% set description = "This is a my custom Page Description" %}
```

For a entry:

```
    {% extends "layouts/_layout" %}
    {% set title = entry.title %}
    {% set description = entry.descriptionField %}
```

.. or if you want to user to have custom control over the entry SEO as well you can always add the same "**seoTitle**" fields to the entry's Channel/Structure/Single and do:

```
    {% extends "layouts/_layout" %}
    {% set title = entry.seoTitle %}
    {% set description = entry.seoDescription %}
```

Comment: Thanks for the clear explanation, naboovalley! This is how I think most do it and I would do it as well.

Comment: Well explained. This is just about exactly what I do, it has worked well. I set up a bunch of global defaults, including OG (open graph) stuff, and let the user override them on a per-entry basis if they want.

Answer (score 14):

Completely biased answer, but check out my [SEOmatic plugin](https://github.com/khalwat/seomatic).  It's pretty comprehensive, and it's free.  If you're running Craft CMS 3, the [SEOmatic plugin is available](https://github.com/nystudio107/craft-seomatic) for Craft CMS 3 as well (but is not free).

Comment: You're biased but to be fair it's a really good plugin so that's allowed. :)

Answer (score 0):

Heres article on my blog about setting up basic SEO functionality for Craft CMS:

http://craftsnippets.com/articles/basic-seo-functionality-for-craft-cms

It presents two options:

- Using pure Twig code for handling `<title>` metatag.
- Setting up basic SEOmetatags using [Seomate plugin](https://plugins.craftcms.com/seomate)